# asp:Textbox off focus?

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2008

I want to save the contents of a multline textbox when off focus - i.e. user has finished typing and clicks outside the textbox so it goes off focus.

I can handle the saving- thats no problem, but is there an off focus function?
I don't mind a javascript version. I must be using asp:TextBox though.

I tried with onFocus, OnServerChange, onKeyUp, but it is not exactly how I want it.
If any of you use Facebook, then it is like the textbox displayed right below the profile picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnBlur` :)

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" onblur="alert(1);" />
```

(I can't recall, off the top of my head, if it will write any unknown server property to the client, I think it does, but if it doesn't, you'll need to add it as an attribute, in code).

-- Edit:

Confirmed that it does, indeed, happily write out unknown properties (onblur is not a property of TextBox control, but it will render in the HTML, so it works).

Comment: +1 perfect... damn I saw onBlur but didn't try it, tried every other one though :(.. feel silly asking such as stupid question now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! and I think I went through the exact same process when I was first looking for something like this as well :)

Comment: ASP.NET behavior by default is to render unknown attributes pretty much anywhere they appear.  Don't know how it handles attributes like class when both it and CssClass are defined.

Comment: @DavidAndres: I thought CssClass renders to Class? So won't that just be a case of having two classes defined?

Answer (score 0):

A multiline textbox should render to a textarea element.  Assign an event handler to its onBlur event, and you should be good.